# Function definiation out of place using struct keyword

Tags: c

im having trouble using structs in C im having this code.

**CORRECTION NOTED**
  There is a semi-colon on my code, sorry my bad

myHeader.h

```
  struct node{
    Token elem;
    void (*push)(Stack[], Token);
    Token (*pop)(Stack[]);
    Token (*peek)(Stack[]);
    boolean (*isEmpty)(Stack[]);
    boolean (*isFull)(Stack[]);
};

typedef struct node Stack;
```

MyMain.c

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include "codes/myHeader.h" <-- im using tc2 by the way so im forced to use this kind of inlcude

some codes..
```

im getting error on the MyHeader.h part when i try compiling it (Assume that the other part of the .c are working) it says that there is an undefined error 'node' and i really don't know whats going on, been trying moving the typedef struct node MyStructure below the struct node { } definition still gives out the same error

BTW im using tc2

Anyone care to point out what im missing?

Comment: naahh it only says Function defination out of place.. by the way i've changed the last error to this cuz the other one is already solved

Comment: So you post a question to a specific problem, get answers for it, and then totally change the question for the new problem you have? I'm voting to close this, it doesn't have any value whatsoever. Not only the question is incomplete, it has no value for future visitors and the answers don't have anything to do with the question.

Comment: its still connected, and in the end i really don't know whats the answer to both related wuestion

Comment: By the way, your `typedef` is after the `struct node` declaration? That's your problem. Just move it before you declare `struct node`.

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef struct node {
   int x;
   int y;
} MyStructure;
```

Same as:

```
struct node {
   int x;
   int y;
};

typedef struct node MyStructure;
```

Example for a stack implementation

```
//definitions
//C99 has #include <stdbool.h> for this
typedef short boolean;
#define true  1
#define false 0

//You may #define YOUR_APIENTRY APIENTRY (from a system header)
#define YOUR_APIENTRY
#define YOUR_APIENTRYP YOUR_APIENTRY*

//predeclarations
struct _Stack;
typedef struct _Stack Stack;

struct _StackImpl;
typedef struct _StackImpl StackImpl;

struct _Element;
typedef struct _Element Element;

//stack implementation function type definitions
typedef void    (YOUR_APIENTRYP pfnPush)     (Stack*, Element);
typedef Element (YOUR_APIENTRYP pfnPop)      (Stack*);
typedef Element (YOUR_APIENTRYP pfnPeek)     (Stack*);
typedef boolean (YOUR_APIENTRYP pfnIsEmpty)  (Stack*);
typedef boolean (YOUR_APIENTRYP pfnIsFull)   (Stack*);

//funct ptr table
struct _StackImpl{
    pfnPush     push;
    pfnPop      pop;
    pfnPeek     peek;
    pfnIsEmpty  isEmpty;
    pfnIsFull   isFull;
};

//stack
typedef struct _Stack{
    Element* elems; //any appropriate container
    size_t elemCount;
    //if you want to replace the implementation using
    //different func tables (polymorphic)
    //StackImpl* funcPtrs; 
} Stack;

//stack element
struct _Element{
    int value;
};

//default implementation /replace NULL's with actual function pointers)
StackImpl defaultStackImpl = 
{
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
};

//function wrappers
void push(Stack* stack, Element elem)
{
    //if you use a polymorphic implementation
    //stack->funcPtrs->push(stack,elem);
    defaultStackImpl.push(stack,elem);
}
```

Comment: works fine on these kinds of data members, how about function pointers?

Comment: Either that or move the typedef to after the struct declaration. I think the problem is that `node` is being referenced before it has been declared.

Comment: That is indeed the primary problem.

Comment: alternative - add forward declaration struct node; before the typedef

Comment: already tried moving the typedef part after the struct node def

Comment: @AlexanderAtanasov wat do u mean by foward declaration

Comment: hmmmm... i've tried using this, please see edited post, the error says function definition out of place

Comment: @Sam by the way, do i have to typedef the function pointers? can't i define them directly inside the structure?

Comment: No, C doesn't have member functions like C++, nor can you add typedefs to structs.

Comment: See above example for how to implement an equivalent to static or polymorphic C++ classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use a bare type named `node`,  that's not right. No such type exists. You need to use either:

```
struct node my_node;
```

or using the `typedef`:

```
MyStructure my_node;
```

Comment: sorry missed out on writing the semi-colon, there is a semi-colon on my code

Comment: @lemoncodes Okay, answer rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a semi-colon after the last } of the struct.